# Where to get replacement bike frame cable entry grommets?

Tags: frames, shifter, parts

Does anybody know where to get more of these ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

These hold shift and/or brake cable ferrules where the cables enter the frame.  Here is what they look on a bike if that helps:

[image]

These specifically are for a Dengfu frame, but it seems all the Chinese open-mold design frames use this same part, and some big-name manufactures as well.  Note that this type has a molded spring-type arm so they clip in the frame without need for fasteners or tools.

Before somebody says "contact Dengfu", they are located on the other side of the world and they are looking to ship frames, I'd prefer to find a closer / more convent source, and this seems to be a relatively standard part so I would figure somebody out there will sell these in relatively small consumer quantities.

The closest I've found so far is:

https://www.excelsports.com/main.asp?page=8&description=Chainstay+Cable+Stop&vendorCode=CERVELO&major=11&minor=11

I suppose I could try these, but the shape is somewhat different (you have to look at the images closely to see, the shape is similar but definitely not exactly the same), and at $8 each for a part that probably does not cost $0.05 to make this seems excessive.

Does anybody know of a source that is an exact match and/or available for a more reasonable price?

Comment: Expect to pay exorbitant amounts for fiddly little parts like this.   If you already have the parts but they're broken, then it may be cheaper/easier to measure and design something for 3D printing.

Comment: Another option may be to run full-length cable housing through both holes, and temporarily keep water out with some tape and/or RTV silicon.

Comment: Seriously, just contact Dengfu. I had numerous deals with open mold vendors, they are open to sell you a spare or two. The shipping might take some time and some companies prefer to ship with EMS only and not with cheaper China Post.

Answer (score 3):

I discover your post because I have a Dengfu frame (recognized it on the photo!) with the same problem. I had a contact with Dengfu (Jame Yang). They can send me a pair for free but I have to pay $10 for the shipping. I found this too expensive and besides, i presme I'll have the same problem after a while. So I just put a nice black strap around the downtube of the frame holding both clips. It's very discreet and cheap!  ;)
Hope this helps and does not come too late!
Rudy

Comment: Could you post a pic?  I'm not sure what you mean by a black strap around the downtube of the frame holding clips.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a picture of the setup. FYI Dengfu is sending me a couple of clips FOC because I refused their shipping costs! I don't know if I will install them though because after  short while the same problem will happen.

[image]